# How to select element from dropdown selenium

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, selenium-chromedriver, html-parsing

I'm just beginner in selenium, and need to get element from dropdown menu with html tag:

```html
<div class="dropdown dropdown-block dropdown--saved-search open">
                            <a id="dropdown1" class="form-control form-control-lg select-control" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                                <span id="selectedSavedSearchName" data-bind="text: SelectedSavedSearchName">Saved Searches</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-block" aria-labelledby="dropdown1" id="SavedSearchListItems" data-bind="foreach: SavedSearches">
                                <li class="dropdown-menu_item" data-bind="click: $root.SavedSearchSelected.bind($parent, $data)">
                                    <span class="RedirectUrl" style="display:none" data-bind="text: SearchUrl">url=twlTCq14LI9OyNaWz8gyGLys61rYhnwWjChZSjB5HlY%3d</span>
                                    <a class="SavedSearchName" data-bind="text: SaveSearchName">avalon</a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-icon-only btn--delete js_btnDeleteSavedSearch" data-bind="click: $root.OpenConfirmationPopupForDeleteSearch.bind($root, $parent)">
                                        <span class="icon">
                                            <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7.667 42.667C7.667 45.6 10.067 48 13 48h21.333c2.934 0 5.334-2.4 5.334-5.333v-32h-32v32zm34.666-40H33L30.333 0H17l-2.667 2.667H5V8h37.333V2.667z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg>

                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            
                                <li class="dropdown-menu_item" data-bind="click: $root.SavedSearchSelected.bind($parent, $data)">
                                    <span class="RedirectUrl" style="display:none" data-bind="text: SearchUrl">url=QiCRRma69RVV8rZtQS3D4d3R%2fwHJwgFlAoBPVUw%2fbZI%3d</span>
                                    <a class="SavedSearchName" data-bind="text: SaveSearchName">buy now</a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-icon-only btn--delete js_btnDeleteSavedSearch" data-bind="click: $root.OpenConfirmationPopupForDeleteSearch.bind($root, $parent)">
                                        <span class="icon">
                                            <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7.667 42.667C7.667 45.6 10.067 48 13 48h21.333c2.934 0 5.334-2.4 5.334-5.333v-32h-32v32zm34.666-40H33L30.333 0H17l-2.667 2.667H5V8h37.333V2.667z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg>

                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            
                                <li class="dropdown-menu_item" data-bind="click: $root.SavedSearchSelected.bind($parent, $data)">
                                    <span class="RedirectUrl" style="display:none" data-bind="text: SearchUrl">url=u14wnnlX4CFa8PPr%2bR9gxXbSGLj98QMWI4AjLKYEdU4%3d</span>
                                    <a class="SavedSearchName" data-bind="text: SaveSearchName">highlander</a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-icon-only btn--delete js_btnDeleteSavedSearch" data-bind="click: $root.OpenConfirmationPopupForDeleteSearch.bind($root, $parent)">
                                        <span class="icon">
                                            <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7.667 42.667C7.667 45.6 10.067 48 13 48h21.333c2.934 0 5.334-2.4 5.334-5.333v-32h-32v32zm34.666-40H33L30.333 0H17l-2.667 2.667H5V8h37.333V2.667z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg>

                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            
                                <li class="dropdown-menu_item" data-bind="click: $root.SavedSearchSelected.bind($parent, $data)">
                                    <span class="RedirectUrl" style="display:none" data-bind="text: SearchUrl">url=S7d%2fikaBedxE9VnjjWxxpLnB%2bvNtgY%2blIW0Xr9X5a3s%3d</span>
                                    <a class="SavedSearchName" data-bind="text: SaveSearchName">kamry</a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-icon-only btn--delete js_btnDeleteSavedSearch" data-bind="click: $root.OpenConfirmationPopupForDeleteSearch.bind($root, $parent)">
                                        <span class="icon">
                                            <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7.667 42.667C7.667 45.6 10.067 48 13 48h21.333c2.934 0 5.334-2.4 5.334-5.333v-32h-32v32zm34.666-40H33L30.333 0H17l-2.667 2.667H5V8h37.333V2.667z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg>

                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            
                                <li class="dropdown-menu_item" data-bind="click: $root.SavedSearchSelected.bind($parent, $data)">
                                    <span class="RedirectUrl" style="display:none" data-bind="text: SearchUrl">url=AOgkSqNgd5UXBdn4NutgXpaFLe%2f%2f2lCxnw8%2fYC7E63Y%3d</span>
                                    <a class="SavedSearchName" data-bind="text: SaveSearchName">parser</a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-icon-only btn--delete js_btnDeleteSavedSearch" data-bind="click: $root.OpenConfirmationPopupForDeleteSearch.bind($root, $parent)">
                                        <span class="icon">
                                            <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7.667 42.667C7.667 45.6 10.067 48 13 48h21.333c2.934 0 5.334-2.4 5.334-5.333v-32h-32v32zm34.666-40H33L30.333 0H17l-2.667 2.667H5V8h37.333V2.667z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg>

                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            
                                <li class="dropdown-menu_item" data-bind="click: $root.SavedSearchSelected.bind($parent, $data)">
                                    <span class="RedirectUrl" style="display:none" data-bind="text: SearchUrl">url=l%2b8avDt52v0eO3kj4dCWdUk97FlMGwWqR6TKmhqxQiY%3d</span>
                                    <a class="SavedSearchName" data-bind="text: SaveSearchName">toyot</a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-icon-only btn--delete js_btnDeleteSavedSearch" data-bind="click: $root.OpenConfirmationPopupForDeleteSearch.bind($root, $parent)">
                                        <span class="icon">
                                            <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7.667 42.667C7.667 45.6 10.067 48 13 48h21.333c2.934 0 5.334-2.4 5.334-5.333v-32h-32v32zm34.666-40H33L30.333 0H17l-2.667 2.667H5V8h37.333V2.667z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg>

                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

But i tried find it by xpath, and no results. I need to click it, and from dropdown select option with name "parser". Who can help, what i'm doing wrong? I'm using python and chromedriver
[screenshot of dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km4td.png)

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: Of course, but unfortunately without authorization you will not get this menu 
https://www.iaai.com/Vehiclelisting/Automobiles

Comment: I see the web page. what drop down is it there? What is the scenario, flow?

Comment: Edited post, and added html code

Answer (score 0):

If a drop down is built using `Select` and `Option` tag, you can use `Select class` from **Selenium**, since this is not the case for you.

You will have to click on drop down like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text() , 'Saved Searches')]"))).click()
```

and then store all the options in a list and iterate the list and use if clause to see if you have a desire element and then click on it.

```
for option in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR , "li.menu_item a.SavedSearchName"):
    if option.text == "buy now":
        option.click()
```

Comment: Launch browser in full screen and try again `driver.maximize_window()`

Comment: I'm using options 
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=800,600")
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

Comment: replace this `options.add_argument("--window-size=800,600")` with `options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")`

Comment: Have another problem, parser is very big, and if i'll change resolution, i'll need to code at all. It worked perfectly, but site was some changed exactly saved searches

Comment: for testing purpose you can increase the resolution to check if it works or not

Comment: I have just that solution for your issue.

Comment: In addition to answer by @cruisepandey, can you try this:

```
search_drop_down = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text() , 'Saved Searches')]")
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", search_drop_down)
```